# vm.max_map_count is set to 262144 but still getting an Error

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to install Elasticsearch in minikube but I cannot proceed because the pod keeps on restarting.

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-16T13:04:46,836+0000", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master",  "message": "stopping ..."  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-16T13:04:46,883+0000", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master",  "message": "stopped"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-16T13:04:46,884+0000", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master",  "message": "closing ..."  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-16T13:04:46,981+0000", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master",  "message": "closed"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-16T13:04:46,987+0000", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.NativeController", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master",  "message": "Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started"  }
```

Upon powering on, my pc  vm.max_map_count is already set to 262144. Because I already have edited the /etc/sysctl.conf yesterday.

```
elk-tut$ sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count=262144
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

I already searched the internet but only setting the the vm.max_map_count to 262144 is the only fix. I wonder why minikube still seeing vm.max_map_count [65530] instead of 262144.

Comment: Have the exact same problem. For a virtual Ubunutu machine which I have set up locally in Virtuall machine, I can change the value with "sysctl -w vm.max_map_count = 262144". With a virtual machine at my provider, this is not possible and always stops at 65530. Have you found a solution yourself?